# Cauchy Integral formula computation

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I got $\int \frac{\sin z}{(z^2+\frac{1}{2})^2}dz=4\sqrt2\pi i \sinh\left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\right)$ where the contour is a circle of radius 3 centered at the origin by splitting up the contour into two semicircles and then using the derivative form of Cauchy's integral formula.  Is the best way to apply Cauchys integral formula in this case?  Does anybody else get the same answer?

Comment: I don't get the same thing, but then I'm a bit rusty so I might be making a mistake. My answer has a $\cosh(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ term. I think the fastest way to solve this is using the residue theorem, and finding the residue at the two poles (of order 2) $\pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$. Did you try that?

Comment: @PhilipCherian I agree with your finding.  I think both residues are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}-\frac{1}{2}\cosh{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}$